# Does this icon of a person on my os x desktop left bottom corner mean it is running os x server?

Tags: macos, server.app

Why is my desktop showing this on the bottom left and how do I turn it off?

[image]

This is not part of my wallpaper, it's something Mac OS X is showing, I think it's something to do with OS X Server which is no longer installed, or something to do with remote access but I don't know.

Comment: I've never seen that icon before.  Do you have multiple people logging into that Mac?  Maybe it has to do with with user is logged in?

Comment: Only one user is logged in.  I think it first appeared after I installed the Server app in Mountain Lion but I'm now on OS X 10.11 el capitan and do not have the Server app.